# Webpack using external modules from CDN

Tags: javascript, redux, external, bundling-and-minification, webpack-2

I am using React with Redux for an application and use Webpack for bundling. I wanted to load some of the libraries from CDN and not to bundle them. This works fine for React and ReactDOM, but I cannot make it work for redux and other libraries without global export. This is my current externals section in the Webpack config:

```
       externals: [
          { "react": "React" },
          { "react-dom": "ReactDOM" },
          {
              "redux": {
                  commonjs: "redux",
                  commonjs2: "redux",
                  amd: "redux"
              }
          }
        ]
```

In the HTML I have a reference to the redux CDN:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/3.6.0/redux.min.js"></script>
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'combineReducers' of undefined
    at Object.__webpack_exports__.a (ui.ts:10)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 749616a…:19)
    ...
```

I haven't got much experience with modules, so maybe I am missing something simple or it is just not possible.

Comment: Try aliasing `redux` as `Redux` (instead of `redux`). The CDN file exports `Redux` and that's how you're probably referencing it in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `Redux` (instead of `redux`). The CDN file exports `Redux` and that's how you're probably referencing it in your code.

```
externals: [
  { "react": "React" },
  { "react-dom": "ReactDOM" },
  { "redux": "Redux"}
]
```